# C++ equivalent of Arraylist.get(index)

Tags: java, c++, vector, arraylist

I have been wanting to learn C++ out of interest and to start of I wanted to see if I could translate some of my java code I had written to solve some project euler problems(I had followed a course a while back so I wanted to see what I remembered). But then I came across this java code:

```
while (x != 0) {
        if(x%10 != 0) {
            digits.add(x%10);
        }
        x /= 10;
    }
```

Which I translated to:

```
std::vector<int> v;
while(x != 0){
    v.push_back(x%10);
    x /= 10;
}
```

With some help of the internet. 
Now the question is, How do I get the a certain value out of this ¨list¨. In Java I can do digits.get(index), How does one do this in c++?

Comment: @Dici At least it's a kinda well formulated question, not _do my homework for me pls_.

Comment: And it is also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221702/accessing-elements-of-a-vector-in-c. 4 words in Google are enough to find the answer on thousands of sites

Comment: Why no `if (x%10 != 0)` in your C++ code?

Comment: I just forgot to add that part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `operator[](std::size_t)`, just like you would with a plain array:

```
int n = v[index];
```

Note that this performs no bounds checking. If you want bounds-checked access, use the [`at()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) member function:

```
int n = v.at(index);
```

The latter throws an `std::out_of_range` exception for out of bounds access.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use [v.at(index);](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/) to get a element from vector.

Also note that `v[index]` does not have range check, but `v.at(index)` will throw `range_error` exception of out of range.