# How can I update a value of a vector or a map

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary, vector

There is 12 speed limits. I would like to make a statistic which counts them separately. How I can update them? I don't want to push a new element every iteration. I just want to update their value every iteration. Is there any method which is better than mine? I started to code like this:

```
if (pSeg->pRule->b_IsRealSpeedLimitValid)
{

    realSpeedLimit validSpeedLimit;

    speedLimitMap.insert(std::pair<int, realSpeedLimit>(10, validSpeedLimit));
    speedLimitMap.insert(std::pair<int, realSpeedLimit>(20, validSpeedLimit));
    speedLimitMap.insert(std::pair<int, realSpeedLimit>(30, validSpeedLimit));
    speedLimitMap.insert(std::pair<int, realSpeedLimit>(35, validSpeedLimit));
    speedLimitMap.insert(std::pair<int, realSpeedLimit>(40, validSpeedLimit));
    speedLimitMap.insert(std::pair<int, realSpeedLimit>(50, validSpeedLimit));
    speedLimitMap.insert(std::pair<int, realSpeedLimit>(60, validSpeedLimit));
    speedLimitMap.insert(std::pair<int, realSpeedLimit>(70, validSpeedLimit));
    speedLimitMap.insert(std::pair<int, realSpeedLimit>(80, validSpeedLimit));
    speedLimitMap.insert(std::pair<int, realSpeedLimit>(90, validSpeedLimit));
    speedLimitMap.insert(std::pair<int, realSpeedLimit>(100, validSpeedLimit));
    speedLimitMap.insert(std::pair<int, realSpeedLimit>(110, validSpeedLimit));

    switch (pSeg->pRule->Num_RealSpeedLimit)
    {
    case 10:
        auto search = speedLimitMap.find(10);
        if (search != speedLimitMap.end())
        {
            ++validSpeedLimit.totalSegmentCount;
            validSpeedLimit.isValid = true;
            segLength += validSpeedLimit.totalSegmentLength;
        }
        break;
    case 20:
        break;
    case 25:
        break;
    case 30:
        break;
    case 40:
        break;
    case 50:
        break;
    case 60:
        break;
    case 70:
        break;
    case 80:
        break;
    case 90:
        break;
    case 100:
        break;
    case 110:
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing elements of a vector in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221702/accessing-elements-of-a-vector-in-c)

Comment: Why not `speedLimitMap[pSeg->pRule->Num_RealSpeedLimit]++`?

Comment: @JasperKent Because it's wrong, is the main flaw - it default-constructs non-existent elements and the incrementing value is actually a member of the element type (plus other actions are taken that you do not account for). please make your technical solutions in answers so they can be properly peer reviewed to avoid misteaching

Comment: I wasn't sure this was the solution, which I why I asked a question as a comment. If you, or the questioner could explain *why* its wrong, then we might come to a solution.

Comment: It doesn't default-construct objects. The `switch` already restricts us to elements that already exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is loads here that you don't need to do.

```
switch (pSeg->pRule->Num_RealSpeedLimit)
{
case 10:
    auto search = speedLimitMap.find(10);
```

Why repeat `10`? You already have it in a *variable*!

```
auto search = speedLimitMap.find(pSeg->pRule->Num_RealSpeedLimit);
```

Now there's no need for a `switch` at all as this'll execute the same for all those numbers.

You also have a bug in that you're not *using* the iterator you obtained via `.find`, but just modifying the local variable `validSpeedLimit` that you copied into each map element. I assume that this is wrong.

---

A further improvement your `.insert` is valid, but verbose. You could use either of the following instead:

```
speedLimitMap.emplace(10, validSpeedLimit));
speedLimitMap[10] = validSpeedLimit;
```

Since `validSpeedLimit` is default-constructed, we don't even need all these copies actually; just default-construct in-place:

```
speedLimitMap.emplace(10, {});
```

---

It's really hard to guess what your program does because you gave no context, but (assuming your `case`s are all supposed to be repeats of the first one, since you talked about "iterations") here's what I'd do:

```
auto& rule = *pSeg->pRule;
if (rule.b_IsRealSpeedLimitValid)
{
    static constexpr const int keys[] = {
       10, 20, 30, 350, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110
    };

    for (const auto i : keys)
       speedLimitMap.emplace(i, {});

    if (rule.Num_RealSpeedLimit)
    {
        if (auto it = speedLimitMap.find(rule.Num_RealSpeedLimit); it != speedLimitMap.end())
        {
            auto& validSpeedLimit = it->second;

            ++validSpeedLimit.totalSegmentCount;
            validSpeedLimit.isValid = true;
            segLength += validSpeedLimit.totalSegmentLength;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I assume that in reality you're using this map later, otherwise the logic of keeping all those elements around really doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

One option is make that firts map automatically. And after that You have proper number so why just dont use it?

```
if (pSeg->pRule->b_IsRealSpeedLimitValid) {

realSpeedLimit validSpeedLimit;

for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= 12; ++i) {
    speedLimitMap.insert(std::pair<int, realSpeedLimit>(i*10, validSpeedLimit));
}

auto search = speedLimitMap.find(pSeg->pRule->Num_RealSpeedLimit);

if (search != speedLimitMap.end()) {
    ++validSpeedLimit.totalSegmentCount;
    validSpeedLimit.isValid = true;

    segLength += validSpeedLimit.totalSegmentLength;
} else {
    std::cerr << "Your number: " << pSeg->pRule->Num_RealSpeedLimit<< " not in database" << std::endl;
}
```

}